# Discord.py | Anyway to make bots seek out embeds that it has sent and delete them all?

Tags: python, discord.py

is there anyway to make a command like `>delembeds` or something that will make the bot seek out all embeds it's sent and delete them? All help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [discord.TextChannel.history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#discord.TextChannel.history) to get the messages and then check if it contains an embed. You can change the limit to `None` if you want but it will be slow, keep in mind the limit counts for every message in the channel with or without an embed.

This will delete every embed in the channel regardless of the author

```py
@bot.command()
async def delembeds(ctx):
    messages_in_channel = await ctx.channel.history(limit=30).flatten()
    for message in messages_in_channel:
        if message.embeds:  # if it has an embed
            await message.delete()

    await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
```